# The mosaic function in GEE is not functional when I filter the date

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, mosaic

I am trying to calculate the NDVI using the Google Earth engine. my area of interest is not covered in one scene so I need to mosaic the required bands. but the mosaic function does not work when I define a specific date although it seems to work without a date.

here is a link to my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a464f6f1f43748ee42721c2447141615

here is my code:

```
var image = l8.filterBounds(table)
           .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',1)
           .filterDate('2023-05-1','2023-08-30');
var RED = image.select('B4');
var NIR = image.select('B5');
var mosaic_red = RED.mosaic();
var mosaic_nir = NIR.mosaic();

 var NDVI = mosaic_nir.subtract(mosaic_red).divide(mosaic_nir.add(mosaic_red));

Map.addLayer(NDVI);
Map.centerObject(table,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code since you didn't share your asset. You also didn't specify in what way this fails. I have to do some guesswork.

Perhaps you filtered down the collection so you didn't have any imagery left. At that point, when calling `mosaic()`, you get an image without bands, leading to `NDVI` without bands.